# Use JavaScript and jQuery to Make a Hyperlink to Play Embedded YouTube Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml, youtube-api

Does anyone know how I would use JavaScript with jQuery to make a hyperlink to play an embedded YouTube video? I know that I could do:

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");
$("#link").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
player.playVideo();
});
```

However, wouldn't this only work if I am using `<embed>` or `<object>`? I am using `<iframe>` to embed the video on my page. Would the `document.getElementById("player")` still work on the `<iframe id="player">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#player')` will still work and find the iFrame. However, to find elements within that iFrame, you will have to use `$('selector', $('#player').contentDocument)`. To find elements in your document while executing javascript within the iframe, you will have to use `parent.$('selector')`. If you want to play a youtube video you can simply use this:

```
$('.youtubeLink').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('iframe').attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qvWZb/)  Btw, use the embedded link you can find on the youtube page as href of your a